# Proof of double negation elimination using natural deduction

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

I am trying to prove that $\neg A \to \bot \vdash A$, I can only use double negation elimination to get the conclusion, but I don't know how to prove double negation elimination.

Below is my proof for $\neg A \to \bot \vdash A$:

1 $\neg A\to\bot$

2 $\neg A$ (assumption)

3 $\bot$ ($\to$e 1, 2)

4 $\neg\neg A$ ($\neg$i 2-3)

5 $A$ (DNE 4)

The rules that can be used would be the basic rules of natural deduction:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean precisely when you say that you want to prove double negation elimination? What rules are you allowed to use?

Comment: $\wedge$e, i.
$\vee$e, i.
$\to$e, i.
$\neg$e, i.
$\bot$e, i.

Comment: What precisely are your rules $\lnot E$, $\lnot I$, $\bot E$, and $\bot I$? Not everyone uses the same names for the same rules. Please edit these into your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rules you list comprise a natural deduction system for intuitionistic logic. The sequent $\lnot A\to \bot\vdash A$ is not valid in intuitionistic logic, so it is not provable in your system.

To prove $\lnot A\to \bot\vdash A$, you need to be working with a natural deduction system for classical logic, which means adding an additional rule to your system. One common choice is to add double negation elimination itself; this makes your proof a valid one. Other common choices are adding reductio ad absurdum (proof by contradiction) or the law of excluded middle.